# Shift+Enter not working in Google Colab (Neither is Clt+Enter)

Tags: google-colaboratory

Since last 1 week, Shift+Enter keyboard shortcut is not working for running a cell in my Colab notebooks. Is is a bug or a settings problem? Do we have any other shortcut for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Does the issue reproduce in an incognito window?

Your question sounds like [this Colab issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/858#issuecomment-553989089), wherein users of the Evernote chrome extension discovered that the extension breaks keyboard shortcuts. If you have that extension installed, I'd recommend disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Chrome. In my case <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> worked, but only if I pressed <kbd>esc</kbd> first to stop the cursor from blinking in the cell.

Fixed it by updating Chrome, removing the Evernote Web Clipper extension, and restarting the browser.